# Back to top button not responding in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, button, jsx

I have been working on a project which happened to have a usual back-to-top button as seen on websites nowadays. But it doesn't seem to work as expected. Source code:

```
<button className='button-arrow' disabled={!visible} style={{display : visible? 'block': 'none'}} onClick={() =>{
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;      
  console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop)
}}> <FaArrowUp  size={20} color='#fff'/> </button>
```

onClicked, I have declared `document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0`.
When I consoled log the output, this is what I got each time I clicked the button. It is expected to go to the top of the site. But as you can see in the output below, it kind of glitches:

```
434
432.22
426.555
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

```
onClick={() => window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'})}
```